# yii CGridView работа с двумя таблицами, связанными через третью

Tags: php, yii, activerecord, cgridview, ar

Суть проблемы в следующем:

Имеются таблицы:

1. country
   id
   name
2. area
   id
   country_id
   name
3. city
   id
   area_id
   name

Необходимо вывести в одном гриде Страны, Области(Регионы) и города, чтоб можно было фильтровать данные по любому из названий( Страна область город ).

В сети полным-полно инфы о том, как отображать связанные таблицы, но вся проблема в том, что таблицы 1 и 3 не связаны между собой напрямую, ввиду чего, неясно даже как прописать relations для дальнейших работ с criteria итд и как таковой инфы на этот счёт найти так и не удалось.

Есть какие-нибудь идеи?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class City extends CActiveRecord {

    // Поле для для фильтра по стране в гриде
    public $country_id;

    public function rules(){
        // тут указать необходимые правила для сценария поиска
    }

    public function relations(){
        return array(
               // связь с регионом
               array('area', 'Area', 'area_id')
        );
    }

    public function geoSearch(){
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->together = true;
        $criteria->with = array(
            'area' => array(
                'with' => array(
                    // соответственно модели Area указать связь со страной
                    'country' => array(
                        'joinType' => 'INNER JOIN',
                    )
                ),
                'together' => true,
                'joinType' => 'INNER JOIN',
            )
        );

        // тут не забывать ставить алиасы таблиц, по аналогии прописать другие условия
        $criteria->compare('country.id', $this->country_id);
        $criteria->compare('t.area_id', $this->area_id);
        $criteria->comapre('t.name', $this->name, true);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria' => $criteria
        ));
    }
}
```